# Running Cast Receiver (H5 application) on Win10 Chrome cannot receive casting from Youtube on Android phone?

Tags: google-cast

My problem: I am following [Google Cast Sample Application Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/sample_apps?hl=zh-cn) to develop a Cast Receiver default receiver application (I have not registered App ID, so I didn’t use a personalized or custom receiver, because I want to use the default receiver to see the effect first), and hosted it on the Firebase platform to achieve access through https. After Chome opened the receiver, the console has been output:

```
 [  0.001s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening net websocket 
cast_receiver_framework.js:742 Lit is in dev mode. Not recommended for production! See https://lit.dev/msg/dev-mode for more information.
ao @ cast_receiver_framework.js:742
cast_receiver_framework.js:837 CAST SDK CAF Version: 3.0.0105
cast_receiver_framework.js:121  [  0.042s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc 
media_player.js:120 CAST SDK MPL Version: 1.0.0.114
cast_receiver_framework.js:577 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc' failed: 
_.h.open @ cast_receiver_framework.js:577
cast_receiver_framework.js:121  [  2.385s] [goog.net.WebSocket] An error occurred: undefined 
vh @ cast_receiver_framework.js:121
uh.A @ cast_receiver_framework.js:614
(anonymous) @ cast_receiver_framework.js:48
jd @ cast_receiver_framework.js:48
qd @ cast_receiver_framework.js:50
_.D @ cast_receiver_framework.js:50
_.h.mm @ cast_receiver_framework.js:580
cast_receiver_framework.js:121  [  2.388s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc closed. 
cast_receiver_framework.js:121  [  2.389s] [goog.net.WebSocket] The WebSocket disconnected unexpectedly: undefined 
vh @ cast_receiver_framework.js:121
uh.A @ cast_receiver_framework.js:614
(anonymous) @ cast_receiver_framework.js:48
jd @ cast_receiver_framework.js:48
qd @ cast_receiver_framework.js:50
_.D @ cast_receiver_framework.js:50
_.h.Ht @ cast_receiver_framework.js:579
cast_receiver_framework.js:121  [  2.389s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Seconds until next reconnect attempt: 1 
cast_receiver_framework.js:121  [  3.394s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc 
cast_receiver_framework.js:577 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc' failed: 
_.h.open @ cast_receiver_framework.js:577
```

It keeps repeating these output logs in the console, and I don't know if it's the reason why the YouTube search on the Android side can't find the casting device.

Or is my understanding wrong, and it is impossible to cast from an Android or ios phone to a cast receiver running on Windows chrome? Can only cast to Google TV devices?

Comment: No, I haven’t continued to study it recently. After watching it for a few days, there was no new progress. I think it may not support casting from Android or iOS to the Web.